# How can I drop this table using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to drop a table called 'New'. I currently have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy

sqlcon = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql://ABSECTDCS100TL/AdventureWorks?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server')3

df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM DimReseller', sqlcon)

df.to_sql('New',sqlcon,if_exists='append', index=False)

sqlalchemy.schema.New.drop(bind=None, checkfirst=False)
```

I am receiving the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'sqlalchemy.schema' has no attribute 'New'
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing here?. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reflect the table into a `Table` object and then call its `drop` method:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Table, MetaData

tbl = Table('New', MetaData(), autoload_with=sqlcon)
tbl.drop(sqlcon, checkfirst=False)
```

If you want to delete the table using raw SQL, you can do this:

```
from sqlalchemy import text

with sqlcon.connect() as conn:
    # Follow the identifier quoting convention for your RDBMS
    # to avoid problems with mixed-case names.
    conn.execute(text("""DROP TABLE "New" """))
    # Commit if necessary
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just out of curiosity, is there anyway of dropping the table using a raw SQL command in sqlalchemy?

Comment: @NicodenoS Added an example.  I'm not a MSSQL user so not sure about the corrrect quoting convention or whether you need a commit after DDL statements on that platform.

Comment: Clean and easy to understand. Thanks. I removed the commit() as it gives me the following error: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'commit'